# SHQueryUserNotificationState returns different results between desktop App and Windows Service

Tags: winapi

When I put the SHQueryUserNotificationState calling inside a Windows Service, it will always return "Busy", but as a Windows desktop demo.exe, it returns the correct result.

How can I get the correct result inside a Windows service?

Comment: Service anyway can not show notifications. So what sense call this from service ?

Comment: What makes you assume that you weren't getting the correct result? A service usually runs in a non-interactive session, so displaying a UI isn't going to work out.

Comment: You need to call `SHQueryUserNotificationState()` in the context of the user session that will be displaying subsequent notification(s).